# How do I assign a new value to a variable based on the value of a selected option of a select tag, retrieve and use the new value of the variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a form where user can choose the currency they want to change and as they choose the currency it reflects the currency symbol next to the Amount label. I want to display the STRING equivalence of the selected currency symbol as a result on the page and I don't know how to achieve this in javascript.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G89PFIUW1OUC

above is a code playground link to what I'm trying to do, I have written the jquery code to alternate the value of select options and display the value of the option next to the Amount label and it works fine if I comment out the function that compares the value of the option value and assigns a new value to the stringcurr variable. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, so I need help.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <span class="color-bold">Cash Back Exchange Currency<span style="color:red;">*</span></span>
  <select class="form-control" id="currSelect">
    <option value="">Select currency</option>
    <option value="&#36;"> United States Dollars (USD) </option>
    <option value="&#163;"> Great Britain Pounds (GBP) </option>
    <option value="&#8364;"> European Euro (EUR) </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <label class="color-bold">Amount  - <span id="curr"></span> <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <input name="forexamount" id="forexamount" class="common" type="number" placeholder="Eg. 200">
</div>
<div id="stringcurr"></div>
```

JS

```
<script>
  var intcurr;
  var currencysymbol = "";

  $("#currSelect")
    .change(function() {

        $("#currSelect option:selected").each(function() {
          currencysymbol = $(this).val();
        });
        $("#curr").text(currencysymbol /* .substring(1,0) */ );

        (function(currencysymbol) {
            if (currencysymbol != "") {
              if (currencysymbol == "&#36;") {
                return intcurr = "USD";
              } else if (currencysymbol == "&#163;") {
                return intcurr = "GBP";
              } else if (currencysymbol == "&#8364;") {
                return intcurr = "EUR";
              } else {
                return false
              }

              $("#stringcurr").text(intcurr);
            })();

          change();
        });
</script>
```

I expect the stringcurr div to show USD if the value of the selected option is $charset or GBP if the value of the selected option is £charset etc by assign the strings to the intcurr variable.

Comment: `<div id="stringcurr"></div>` can be a `span` like `<span id="stringcurr"></span> 
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler approach is add a data attribute to each `<option>` with the currency text values and use jQuery `data()` to access them.

Also you need to chain the `change()` method trigger for the page load

```js
$("#currSelect").change(function() {
  // get selected data or make it empty string if undefined
  var curr = $(this).find(':selected').data('curr') || '';
  $('#curr, #stringcurr').text(curr);
   // trigger event on page load
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <span class="color-bold">Cash Back Exchange Currency<span style="color:red;">*</span></span>
  <select class="form-control" id="currSelect">
    <option value="">Select currency</option>
    <option value="&#36;" data-curr="USD"> United States Dollars (USD) </option>
    <option value="&#163;" data-curr="GBP"> Great Britain Pounds (GBP) </option>
    <option value="&#8364;" data-curr="EUR"> European Euro (EUR) </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <label class="color-bold">Amount  - <span id="curr"></span> <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
  <input name="forexamount" id="forexamount" class="common" type="number" placeholder="Eg. 200">
</div>
<div id="stringcurr"></div>
```

Comment: tried running it in the playground and it didn't work. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G89ROBA97PBO

Comment: That's because you are running it before the `<select>` exists. See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Works fine when either move script tag or wrap in `$(function(){ })`